# Entering a 64 bit integer into Excel 2013

Tags: excel, 64-bit

I am attempting to enter 64 bit integers into Excel without success

For example, if I enter

8940964625324625950   Excel automatically converts it to

8940964625324620000

How can I force Excel to just accept the value I provide? Is it even possible? Even if I can force it, will Excel simply convert these numbers back when opened on a different machine with different settings?

Comment: Excel does not support 64-bit integers. It is treated as a double (floating point), and the integer precision is only good up to 2^53. Using *text* would work, but then such is no longer a number.

Comment: No new functionality is added in the 64-bit office releases (although new features are added between versions, just no support for 'big integers' .. yet, anyway). A 64-bit release just means they were compiled to run natively on 64-bit (no WoW64, 64-bit address space) ;-)

Comment: The only reason to use 64-bit software is if you need to address more than 4GB of RAM. There is virtually no other advantage whatsoever. Some even claim it can be slower, because it consumes twice as much space in L2 cache than the 32-bit softwares to perform the same task.

Comment: Off-topic: Not programming-related...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Excel does not support 64-bit integers, numbers are treated as doubles and the precision is limited (aparently to 15 digits).

You can still display `8940964625324625950` in a cell though, as long as you change its Format to Text in the cell properties.